# SQL: Select all entries where a particular set of fields is duplicated in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a query to select all entries from all rows, where a particular 2 column pair is duplicated.  So, for instance, if my table is `(id int, Project varchar, Version varchar, Deployer varchar, Date DateTime)`, I want to get all rows in which there is a duplicate Project/Version.  I've done this

```
SELECT *
FROM Deployments
GROUP BY Project, Version
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

But that only seems to get me the first row for each Project/Version pair.  I want to get all rows.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a join where you join your grouped data to select only rows that fit.

In my case which have the same project number and Version

```
SELECT *
FROM Deployments d INNER JOIN 
(SELECT Project, Version
FROM Deployments
GROUP BY Project, Version
HAVING count(*) > 1) dd ON dd.Project = d.Project AND dd.Version = d.Version;
```

Comment: This isn't a self-join.

Answer (score 0):

Using exists logic is one way to do this:

```
SELECT d1.*
FROM Deployments d1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Deployments d2
              WHERE d2.id <> d1.id AND
                    d1.Project = d2.Project AND d1.Version = d2.Version);
```

Your current query, which uses aggregation, is off, because it uses `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY`.  A valid version might be:

```
SELECT d1.*
FROM Deployments d1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Project, Version
    FROM Deployments
    GROUP BY Project, Version
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) d2
    ON d1.Project = d2.Project AND
       d1.Version = d2.Version;
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, window functions are an easy method:

```
select d.*
from (select d.*, count(*) over (partition by project, version) as cnt
      from deployments d
     ) d
where cnt >= 2
```